# How do I get anything from popstate?

Tags: javascript, html5-history, popstate

I have read all of the Mozilla docs regarding push/pop state. I think I am missing an essential piece of the puzzle to make it work. pushstate is updating the address bar as expected.

But how do I get the page back? Basically I use pushState like so

```
window.history.pushState({page: formattedTitle}, item.title, formattedTitle);
```

but then I want to get `formattedTitle` back from popstate so I can run `getDetail(formattedTitle)` function. But this is not working.

```
$(window).bind('popstate', function(event){

        getDetail(JSON.stringify(event.state)) <- I want this to be getDetail(formattedTitle)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(event.state));
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried using `history.back()` ?

Comment: Did you know that `popstate` does not fire when you use `.pushState()` or `.replaceState()`? When the user navigates forward or backward or `history.go()`, `history.forward()`, `history.back()` are used the event fires.

Comment: But how do I know if to use history.back or forward? Yes I do know that they don't fire for pushstate- but that's not where I'm getting stuck.

Comment: If `location === 'url.php'` then run your code. Change `url.php` to your url. You don't have access to a function if you're not on the correct page. No, `location` does not have to be written `window.location` or window.location.href`, `location` works just fine.